# The man and the woods

Tags: story

A man is being chased into the woods by an evil king. The king has stated the man will not be chased once he is leaving the forest. The king is slightly mad, but knows the entire forest is too long for the man to keep outrunning him and his guards, who are on horse back. That is, before the man reaches the end of the forest they will have caught up with him.

How long does the man have to run for the king and his guards to stop chasing him?

---

*It's my first (semi) riddle; I just felt like posting it.  I hope these 'joke' kinds of riddles are allowed.*

Comment: I'm no expert, but shouldn't trees make the pursuers dismount?

Comment: Sure, leave it to a fictional character to find a flaw in my riddle :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How long? Well I guess that depends on the mans speed, but how far:

> At most, half the length of the forest.

the king has stated the man will not be chased once he is leaving the forest

> After passing a 'half way' point, he is no longer running 'into' the forest, but rather running out of it so he will no longer be chased.

Alternate, albeit silly answers:

> The man is driving so he doesn't have to run at all! Maybe the king could have had the forest transformed into a treadmill in which the man can NEVER escape! The man starts jumping around the place like a maniac continually 'leaving' the forest vertically until he escapes.

Comment: it was rather silly but you're right :P wasn't that hard, was it fun though?

Comment: I'd give you an other +1 if i could, nice alternate answer xD

Answer (score 13):

He can enter the forest,

> turn around, and leave the forest.

So not long at all.

Answer (score 8):

He will not be chased once he take a step into the forest and turn back. Because

> He will be leaving the forest. You answer is one step or zero.

Comment: Like Mark N and andrew smith are both right, you could do it both ways. well done :)

Answer (score 5):

You could:

> Walk backward into the forest. As soon as the King and his man sees you, walk forward

Answer (score 0):

He needs @ least 0.5 meter and get out back.

> If we consider that a normal person will move 0.5 meter in single step, so that is move one step in and the other will be backward which is out and so the king loose.